# Ошибки при создании Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте.

Помогите решить проблемы при создании Navigation Drawer, делал по [инструкции](http://habrahabr.ru/post/236567/).
Не могу понять, что не так, делаю точно по инструкции. Помогите, пожалуйста, в программировании под андройд новичок, делал на Android Studio.  
Еще уточнение: ошибки пишет, когда приложение запускается на эмуляторе андройд.

Вот лог проблем:

```
02-20 11:22:09.289    1183-1183/ru.com.amado E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:735)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1652)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:914)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:502)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:735)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1652)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:914)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:502)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Покажите код активити, у вас тут несколько ошибок, проще будет там указать на них

Comment: Спасибо, только уже не надо реализовал по другой инструкции, изменил под себя и все работает. Вопрос забыл удалить.)

Comment: А как удалить вопрос, подскажите.?